# VueJs submit multiple rows array in form

Tags: forms, vuejs2

I have a form, which has a vue componenet that allows users to create additional input lines in the form.

I am having an issue getting all of these input lines to submit for the axios request, currently it only outputs the last added rows input.

Typically, in a normal PHP form, I would just make the field an array (name="MultiRow[]"), however I am lost at doing this in Vue and struggling to find any doc that covers this.

Here is the component in my form:

```
<div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
    <fieldset class="mt-6">
            <div class="mt-6">
                    <response-set-input v-model="fields.response"></response-set-input>
            </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Here is my Vue File for form submission:

```
<script>

import Switch from '../../components/StatusToggle';

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      fields: {},
      errors: {},
      statusToggle: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggled(toggleOn){
        statusToggle: toggleOn
    },
    submit() {
      this.errors = {};
      axios.post('/submit', this.fields).then(response => {
        alert('Message sent!');
      }).catch(error => {
        if (error.response.status === 422) {
          this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
        }
      });
    },
  },
   components: {
       statusToggle: Switch
   }
}
</script>
```

Here is my component code:

```
<template>
    <div>
    <div class="m-2"  v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="index">

        <div class="col-span-12 sm:col-span-3 mb-1">
            <label for="responseTitle" class="block text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-700">Response</label>
            <input 
            id="responseTitle" 
            class="mt-1 form-input block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5"
            type="text"
            name="fields.response[]"
            :value="responseInput"
            @input="onInput($event.target.value)"/>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2">
            <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-2.5 py-1.5 border border-transparent text-xs leading-4 font-medium rounded text-gray-700 bg-green-100 hover:bg-indigo-50 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-300 focus:shadow-outline-indigo active:bg-indigo-200 transition ease-in-out duration-150"  @click="addRow">
                Add new Response
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-2.5 py-1.5 border border-transparent text-xs leading-4 font-medium rounded text-gray-700 bg-red-100 hover:bg-indigo-50 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-300 focus:shadow-outline-indigo active:bg-indigo-200 transition ease-in-out duration-150" @click="removeRow(index)">
                Remove
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    props: ['responseInput'],
  data () {
    return {
      rows: [],
      stopRemoval: true,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    rows () {
      this.stopRemoval = this.rows.length <= 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(responseInput){
        this.$emit('input', responseInput),
        console.log(responseInput)
    },
    addRow () {
      let checkEmptyRows = this.rows.filter(row => row.number === null)

      if (checkEmptyRows.length >= 1 && this.rows.length > 0) {
         return
      } 

      this.rows.push({
        responseTitle: null,
      })
    },

    removeRow (rowId) {
      if (!this.stopRemoval) {
         this.rows.splice(rowId, 1)
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.addRow()
  }
}
</script>
```

How do I submit the multiple rows to the form submission with Vue?

Answer (score 1):

There's a decent amount wrong with your code, I suggest that you read the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/).

Just to name a few things:

1. You shouldn't update a `prop` in a component as it will get overridden when the parent updates, `props: ['responseInput'],` and `:value="responseInput"`
2. You're not passing any `prop` called `responseInput`, `v-model` passes a `prop` called `value`.
3. Vue is [only reactive on properties that processed during instance initialisation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) and that means it doesn't know about `response` on `fields: {},`
4. You're using  `rows` (which is good), but then you're only emitting the prop you passed in `responseInput`. I think `:value="responseInput"` is supposed to be `:value="row"`